# Question on Feynman's Proof of Energy Conservation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

[image]

Since this is two-dimensional motion, why would $m(dv/dt)$ not have some directionality in addition to being the rate of change of the magnitude of momentum? Is Feynman assuming that the directionality doesn't change in infinitesimal time?

Comment: He clearly states that the direction changes, it is tangential to the surface

Answer (score 0):

If $v$ is treated as the velocity instead of the speed of the object then $m(dv/dt)$ has direction and would be simply the rate of change of momentum, rather than the rate of change *of the magnitude* of the momentum.

The reason for this imprecision probably stems from the two definitions of kinetic energy: it can be calculated as $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$, where $v$ is the speed of the object, or $\frac{1}{2}m(\textbf v\cdot\textbf v)$ where $\textbf v$ is the velocity of the object.

If we use the first definition then the rate of change of kinetic energy is dependent on $m(dv/dt)$, which is directionless.

If we use the second definition then it is dependent on $m(d\textbf v/dt)$ which has direction, and is therefore not the rate of change *of the magnitude* of the momentum, but simply the rate of change of the momentum.

Feynman does not use vector analysis till [later in the chapter](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_13.html), so he is precise in saying that $m(dv/dt)$ is the rate of change *of the magnitude* of the momentum.

But shouldn't he then write the "*magnitude of the force* in the direction of motion", instead of the "force in the direction of motion"? No. Since a component of a vector in a particular direction is a scalar, so it is superfluous to say the magnitude of a scalar.

Hopefully this helps.